# Revert CSS if user clicks on another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery UI accordion that includes a right arrow for each header element. When the user clicks the header to display the content, the arrow changes to a down arrow. When the user clicks the header to hide the content the arrow changes back to it's original form.

My problem comes when the user clicks on an additional section header without first closing the previous section. If the user clicks on section 1, the arrow will change. If the user then clicks on section 2, the section 2 arrow will change but the section 1 arrow will stay in the downward position. I need the arrow to change back to a right facing arrow if the user clicks on any of the other section headers.

Here is my script:

```
var toggleState = true;

$("#wholesale section").on("click", function () {
    if(toggleState) {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#x25BC;");
        $(this).css("background", "#ececec");
    } else {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#9658;");
        $(this).css("background", "#f7f7f7");
    }
    toggleState = !toggleState;
});
```

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TS57R/1/

Comment: I assume that the content of header1 should be hidden as well?

Comment: you can do it easily without jquery UI. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/TS57R/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [activate-event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)

```
$("#wholesale").on("accordionactivate", function (e, ui) {
    ui.oldHeader.find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#x25BC;");
    ui.oldHeader.css("background", "#ececec");
    ui.newHeader.find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#9658;");
    ui.newHeader.css("background", "#f7f7f7");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TS57R/)

---

Else try something like

```
var $sections = $("#wholesale section").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $sections.not(this).removeClass('open').css("background", "#f7f7f7").find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#x25BC;");

    if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
        $this.find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#9658;");
        $this.css("background", "#f7f7f7");
    } else {
        $this.find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#x25BC;");
        $this.css("background", "#ececec");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MsUTj/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to every button that you have and on every click you revert every button to the "normal" position and then toggle the arrow that was clicked.

```
$("#wholesale section").on("click", function () {
    $(".buttons").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#9658;");
        $(this).css("background", "#f7f7f7");
    })
    $(this).find(".dropdown-arrow").html("&#x25BC;");
    $(this).css("background", "#ececec");
});
```

Add a class called button to every button you have. This way you dont need the toggle either. Unless you want it to be collapsible.